# Unable to highlight a link on a webpage and then select from the dropdown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

After opening the *www.netiq.com* link, I am trying to highlight **Support** and select **Documentation** from the dropdown using selenium webdriver.

HTML code:

```
<ul>
<li id="nav_solutions" class="large">
<li id="nav_products" class="large">
<li id="nav_industry" class="">
<li id="nav_service" class="active hover">
<a id="hdr_support_main" href="/services/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'header', 'support', 'main');" data-di-id="#hdr_support_main">
<strong>Support</strong>
<i class="downarrow"/>
<i class="arrow"/>
</a>
<div style="display: block;">
<ul>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a id="hdr_support_documentation" href="https://www.netiq.com/documentation/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'header', 'support', 'documentation');" data-di-id="#hdr_support_documentation">
Documentation
<i class="arrow"/>
</a>
</li>
```

I tried writing this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.netiq.com/")
time.sleep(5)
# select=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='hdr_support_main']"))
# driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='hdr_support_documentation']").click()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("hdr_support_main"))

select.select_by_visible_text("hdr_support_documentation")
```

Error: Message: Select only works on  elements, not on

Please help.

Comment: Please post the actual, full error message. The problem is, as is stated in the error message, that you are using the `Select` class on an element that is not a `SELECT` element. It just looks like one. To solve this you will need to click the dropdown element and then click the desired option from the exposed list. It's just like any other HTML, Selenium will only interact with visible elements so you need to click the dropdown to expose the options.

Comment: The entire error message is not showing, looks like its cropped.
here it is:
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you have to move the cursor in the "Support" element, with:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(support).perform()
```

The entire code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.netiq.com/")
support= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav_service']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(support).perform()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
docButton= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='hdr_support_documentation']")))

docButton.click()
```

Comment: Thanks Davide, it worked with chrome but fails with firefox.
Error message: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: performActions

Comment: FF driver doesn't support `ActionChains` yet.